# scrollTop value changes immediately after setting

Tags: javascript, css, scroll

I have some simple markup...

```
<div class="container">

    <div id="conversation">...</div>

    <div class="keyboard">...</div>

</div>
```

Styled as a vertical flexbox...

```
.container {
    margin: 1em 1em 0;
    max-width: 30em;
    margin-left: auto;
    margin-right: auto;
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: column;
    justify-content: space-between;
    height: 100vh;
}

#conversation {
    overflow-y: scroll;
    box-sizing: border-box;
    margin-bottom: auto;
    flex: 1 1 80%;
}

.keyboard {
    padding: 2rem;
    box-sizing: border-box;
}
```

And I simply want to move the scroll position of `.conversation` all the way to the bottom:

```
var scrollConvo = function() {
    var convo = document.getElementById('conversation');
    console.log('scrollTop', convo.scrollTop); // scrollTop 174
    console.log('scrollHeight', convo.scrollHeight); // scrollHeight 426
    convo.scrollTop = convo.scrollHeight;
    console.log('scrollTop', convo.scrollTop); // scrollTop 252
}
```

But this doesn't work as expected. The scroll position moves, but not all the way to the bottom. And as you see in the comments next to the `console.log` statements, the value is *not* getting set to what I'm expecting. I have no explanation for the resulting value. Why isn't `scrollTop` 426?

**Update 1**
I made a working jsfiddle that does what I want, but I'm not sure why it works but mine does not: http://jsfiddle.net/khj4903t/48/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, `scrollHeight` is the actual content height of the element.

On the other hand `scrollTop` is the amount of actual scroll that has occurred .

If the element height is smaller than the `scrollHeight` a scrollbar will appear. The allowed scroll range is from 0 to (element height - scroll height).

So an element is 100 px in height and has a content of 250 pixels. So 150 pixels are hidden (*and available for the `scrollTop`*).

- element height: 100px
- `scrollHeight`: 250px
- initial scrollTop: 0

The element can scroll for 150 pixels before it reaches the bottom. Setting it to a higher value will only set it to its max. So setting it to 250 will only set it to 150.

Comment: Ok thanks. This is helpful. But does that explain the results I'm seeing? If it defaults to the max scrollTop, why isn't it working as expected (by accident)

Comment: For me, it moves the scroll position, but not to the very bottom. It's alway leaves a little bit hidden below. I don't understand how/why

Comment: @emersonthis it works fine for me on your fiddle. Always moves to bottom when adding a message.